# Probability that a sample mean is between two values using Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, mean

Mean is $2.707$, standard deviation is $.049$, sample of $35$ is drawn from the population.
What is the probability that the mean price for the sample was between $2.683$ and $2.716$? It was suggested that the Central Limit theorem be used.

Comment: Make sure to add the self-study tag and mention what you've tried already.

Comment: Because this is a typical homework/self-study question, the question should have the `self-study` tag. Please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info to see how you should modify your question (tell us what you've tried, where you get stuck).

Comment: Are the quoted mean and s.d. population quantities or sample quantities? Assuming they're population quantities, what does the CLT theorem tell you?